# cURL to Python conversion - Advice

Tags: python, curl

Afternoon guys,

After a little help if possible please. I'm trying to convert a cURL command set with filters into a python script to embed into Power Bi. The original syntax is:

```
curl \
--url 'https://BASE_URL/stats' \
--request POST \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
--data '{
 "filters": [
 {
 "name": "activity_id", 
 "comparison": "=", 
 "values": ["803ac529-700c-4735-8e34-1ecf36ca8145"]
 }
 ], 
 "parameters": [
 "total_player_load", 
 "total_duration"
 ],
 "group_by": [
 "athlete"
 ]
}'
```

And my python code is:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN',
}

data = {
  '{ "filters": [ { "name": "activity_id", "comparison": "': '", "values": ["803ac529-700c-4735-8e34-1ecf36ca8145"] } ], "parameters": [ "total_player_load", "total_duration" ], "group_by": [ "athlete" ] }'
}

response = requests.post('https://BASE_URL/stats', headers=headers, data=data)
```

When printing the response I get:

```
<Response [422]>
```

Just wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction if possible.

Comment: `curl` is using `"comparison": "="` but Python has `"comparison": "': '"` - is that the cause of the [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) error?

Comment: I would recommend to use Postman for debugging such cases

Comment: Ken I did try with both, but unfortunately the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 data = {
                     "filters": {"name": "activity_id", "comparison": "': '", "values": ["803ac529-700c-4735-8e34-1ecf36ca8145"]},
                     "parameters": {[ "total_player_load", "total_duration" ], "group_by": [ "athlete" ]}         
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a dict with this format:

```
data = {
  '{ "filters": [ { "name": "activity_id", "comparison": "': 
'", "values": ["803ac529-700c-4735-8e34-1ecf36ca8145"] } ], "parameters": [ "total_player_load", "total_duration" ], "group_by": [ "athlete" ] }'
}
```

Where the key is `'{ "filters": [ { "name": "activity_id", "comparison": "'` and the value is the rest of your string.

Try editing your data into a proper dict, like:

```
data = {
    "filters": [
        {
            "name": "activity_id", 
            "comparison": " ", 
            "values": ["803ac529-700c-4735-8e34-1ecf36ca8145"] 
        } 
    ], 
    "parameters": [ "total_player_load", "total_duration" ],
    "group_by": [ "athlete" ] 
}
```

and use `requests`'s `json` keyword like this:

```
requests.post('https://BASE_URL/stats', headers=headers, json=data)
```

In this case you might as well remove the `content-type` header, as `request` will automatically add it.

Comment: Thanks @UziGoozie, I slightly changed  this part "comparison": " ", TO "comparison": " = ", and get a response code of 200 now which is cool. What's the best way to print this to the terminal now? Thanks again

Comment: Depends. You may use something like a `response.status_code`  to get the status code of the response and make any checks, `response.headers` to get a dict of all headers in the response, or `response.text` and `response.content` in order to get the body of the text. If it's a json, you may want to try `response.json()` which returns the body as dict if it's a json. There is a lot of documentation regarding requests, you may want to check [the official documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) or this [great guide](https://realpython.com/python-requests/).